# call a method of controller class with es6 style from directive template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want call a method of controller class with ES6 style from directive template like this :

my directive :

```
import angular from 'angular';

function dpGrid() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            options: '='
        },
        template: require('./grid.directive.html')
    }
}

export default angular.module('directives.dpGrid', [])
    .directive('dpGrid', dpGrid)
    .name;
```

a segment of my directive template :

```
<a class="btn btn-info" ng-click="delete(item)">delete</a>
```

and I want call delete() method of this  controller from directive template :

```
export default class userController {

    constructor($scope) {
        this.$scope=$scope;    
    }

    delete(item){

        console.log("item : ",item);
    }


}
userController.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

and I cant use controller attrib in directive like this :

```
controller:'userController'
```

because I want use this directive with multi controller

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call your directive from your controller.
A directive can be used in controller or directly in DOM via attribute.

I don't see why you want to call a controller method in a directive.
A directive is made for DOM manipulation.